# Removing Extra Space in Windows UI TreeView

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm using `TreeView` from `Windows UI Library` in my UWP Apps, using this code:

```
<ui:TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0" Margin="0"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Top" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ui:TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ui:TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ui:TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ui:TreeView.RootNodes>
        <ui:TreeViewNode Content="Flavors" IsExpanded="True">
            <ui:TreeViewNode.Children>
                <ui:TreeViewNode Content="Vanilla" />
                <ui:TreeViewNode Content="Strawberry"/>
            </ui:TreeViewNode.Children>
        </ui:TreeViewNode>
    </ui:TreeView.RootNodes>
</ui:TreeView>
```

[image: TreeView]

How to remove that extra space?
I try to set paddings and margins to `0` still didn't remove the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra space in xaml visual tree looks like this:

[image]

And actually these two textblocks are used for multiple selection:
[image]

So to be honest it's not a good idea to think about removing them as

1. You are trying to break the internal function in treeview.
2. Common ways to customize the treeviewitem style is to re-write the style for treeviewitem from your own code. However the default style for treeviewitem is not doced . Which makes us hard to find the entry to modify this.

As a result, if we really need to do this, we may have to create treeview ourselves or submit a feature request on either [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/) or [here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform). So personally I would recommend you just leave it there if that does not have a big impact.

Answer (score -1):

```
  <Style TargetType="ui:TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" /> 
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" /> 

        </Style>

this can possibly work
```